# Make data in a div formattable ( bold, italic..) with Js

Tags: javascript, html

The title is hard to understand, but here is my problem. Currently, I use 4 buttons (A, B, C and D) to display 4 different texts when you click on them. Clicking on a button will also have an impact on a graphic but that's not the point.

These 4 texts are integrated directly in the div tag, and the names of the buttons between these tags

I would like to have the possibility to format the text of "data-ans". Add some bold, or italic for exemple. But not all the text , just a part of it (for exemple the exclamation point in "Hello!")

```js
function setUpPortfolioButtonClick() {
  const portfolioButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("portfolio-button");
  for (var i = 0, len = portfolioButtons.length; i < len; i++) {
    portfolioButtons[i].addEventListener('click', event => {
      setPlan(event.currentTarget.id);
    });
  }
}

function setSelectedPortfolioActive() {
  const portfolioButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("portfolio-button");
  for (var i = 0, len = portfolioButtons.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (portfolioButtons[i].id === selectedPlan) {
      portfolioButtons[i].classList.add("portfolio-active");
    } else {
      portfolioButtons[i].classList.remove("portfolio-active");
    }
  }
}

function setupPortfolioDescription() {
  const portfolioDescription = document.getElementById("portfolioDescription");
  const selectedPortfolio = document.getElementById(selectedPlan);
  portfolioDescription.textContent = selectedPortfolio.dataset.ans;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-list">
  <div class="portfolio-button" id="a" data-id="b" data-ans="Hello !">
    <p class="portfolio-name">A</p>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-button" id="c" data-id="d" data-ans="Bonjour !">
    <p class="portfolio-name">B</p>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-button" id="e" data-id="f" data-ans="Hi !">
    <p class="portfolio-name">C</p>
  </div>
  <div class="portfolio-button" id="g" data-id="h" data-ans="Hallo !">
    <p class="portfolio-name">D</p>
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="portfolio-selection-display" id="portfolioDescription"></div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make it a [mcve]. There are for example no event handlers on the buttons and no portfolioDescription.

Comment: You should change the classList of the text to a css style

Comment: 1. set `portfolioDescription.innerHTML` instead of `portfolioDescription.textContent` 2. add HTML like `<strong>` to your `data-ans`

Comment: Why can't you use CSS to format the text? Or use `classList.add()`, which you already use for the buttons?

Comment: Lastly delegate from the closest container. That saves several event listeners

Comment: And toggle
`portfolioButtons[i].classList.toggle("portfolio-active",portfolioButtons[i].id === selectedPlan);`

Comment: I made a edit on my post, I would like to make bold not the whole sentence but just a part of it

Comment: @ChrisG I did that , works perfectly and easy to use. I just had to play a bit with my classes ! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format text directly inside JavaScript like this:

- Make text bold: `element.style.fontWeight = "bold";`
- Make text italic: `element.style.fontStyle = "italic";`
- Make text underlined: `element.style.textDecoration = "underline";`

The CSS properties are:

```
font-weight
font-style
text-decoration
```

I hope this answers your question, though it‘s not very clear